# Alexa not uttering speech response from skill, even though card is appearing

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

My Alex a skill consults an API and returns some data, different data according to the request. It's written in node.js. And it worked for a couple of years.

Then it stopped responding on the first time of asking. Now it's not talking to me at all. And yet the card dutifully appears on my phone, demonstrating that the data is being retrieved OK.

I've just logged the response object which the lambda is returning, and it looks fine to me. Here it is:

```
{
"version": "1.0",
"response": {
    "outputSpeech": {
        "type": "PlainText",
        "text": "as of 06:34 unofficial range estimate is Between 82 and 131 miles"
    },
    "card": {
        "type": "Standard",
        "title": "Battery status for Leaf1malc",
        "text": "As of:\t2020/03/23 06:34\nYou have 78.93% battery or 11 out of 12 bars\nGOM Estimate\t103 A/C on, or 109  A/C off\nCynical estimate\tBetween 82 and 131 miles\n\tThe car is not plugged in.",
        "image": {
            "largeImageUrl": "https://gb.nissanconnect.eu/Content/static/images/nissan/my-leaf.jpg"
        }
    },
    "shouldEndSession": true
}
```

This all works as expected both in the Lambda test harness and also in the Alexa skill development console.

I've just refactored the code to use **async** and **await**. This was in the hope of unknotting the usual tangle of callback chains, to make it easier to debug. Once I'd got that running, it went right back to the behaviour I got in the first place.

I've googled and I can find nobody else with this problem. And it emerged before any change in my code, though I've had to update the node.js version as Amazon were complaining the Lambda was using a depracted version.

Current node.js version is 10.

Please take a look at my response object, and see what I'm doing wrong.

ps. Just tried it with SSML, still no voice.

Comment: I now think the problem is that the framework is timing out. I read the timeout for an Alexa lambda is 8 seconds, either that's gone down or the underlying service now runs more slowly. I'm trying to get DeferredResponse to give my lambda a little more elbow room, but I'm not even sure if DeferredResponse is supposed to work for Custom skills that don't use the more specialised interfaces.

Comment: Here's the thing. The login to Nissan, needed to get the access token for subsequent calls, is taking slightly more than 8 seconds, about 8400ms. I thought I could, at least, do the login separately in a launch request, but even that seems to be taking too long. I wonder if I can get around this by hijacking the account linking, but it's a lot of work (have to produce something resembling an OAuth2 service).  and I don't know if a get accesstoken call prior to running the lambda is going to count towards the 8 seconds. DeferredResponse is rejected with 401.